# Where can I find the trip curve for this circuit breaker?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a Westinghouse Cat. No. B10 2020C Type 1 Indoor Enclosure, and I'd like to find the [trip curve](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92969/how-to-predict-when-the-electrical-infrastructure-on-my-1950s-rental-is-going-th) for the breakers.  Any idea where I can find this graph?

[image: Westinghouse Cat. No. B10 2020C Type 1]
[image: The switches in the breaker box]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: Can you post a clearer photo of the breakers, and indicate which breaker you're having trouble with?

Comment: The breaker name and type would provide more than the panel type.

Comment: @EdBeal oh so I've posted a picture of the User Interface and that's it?  Where would the breaker be located?

Comment: Added some more detailed photo's if that helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just followed the link. The trip values for the breakers are the numbers on the handles. You have at least 3 different sizes in your panel the red, blue & black  (the top left one is the main 240V 100A) the blue and reds are the 120V 15 amp & 20 amp the top right is a 240V and there should be a number on the handle that is its amperage. The numbers you want are the ampacities of the breaker they should trip close to this value. the normal load for a breaker is 80% of the value on the handle. As breakers age or have been tripped many times sometimes they do trip early. If you need the curve values we need the type and brand. The type is normally something like "QP".

Answer (score 3):

Your panel uses type BR breakers -- these are currently made by Eaton.  The time-current curves are available [here](http://www.eaton.com/ecm/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&allowInterrupt=1&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&noSaveAs=0&Rendition=Primary&dDocName=1063683065156).