# Federal pacific breaker panel problems

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a FPB panel in my home. I'm losing power in different areas of home but no breakers have tripped. Now I have a tracing nightmare.

Also what is the function of the adjusting screw?

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, take a look at @ThreePhaseEel 's definitive answer on everything Federal Pacific here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/62506/91556

Comment: What's the first question? You had a question mark on a statement, which I've removed. What adjusting screw? Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: And the TL;DR of that link is that this panel is very likely trying its best to burn your house down, and it needs immediate attention; likely a full replacement.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing panel please?

Comment: Is it a stablock FPE panel?  Stablocks have bus’s issues and the breakers are notorious for not tripping. The only thing I will do to a stablock panel is replace it. Federal pacific panels have a high likelihood of causing a fire.