# Federal Pacific Stab- Lock verses bolted in panels

Tags: electrical

I have a 1961, Apartment with Bolted on panels vrs the Stab-lock is bolted on safer?

Comment: You have two identical questions, please delete one. Not clear what you are asking. Stablok is a brand with known problems. Bolted on is a technical yen that can apply to many brands. What do you actually have? Pictures would help.

Comment: If this is an apartment, as in a rental, there's nothing you can or should legally be doing in the panel anyway.

Comment: Good read: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62320/should-all-federal-pacific-panels-be-replaced

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about Federal Pacific Electric in both cases (bolt-on and snap-in, both exist under the "Stab-Lok" name), the whole thing needs to be replaced promptly either way. The internal mechanism has several problems according to http://fpe-info.org/hazardous_fpe_171110.pdf which has nothing to do with the bus connection method:

- Breakers often don't trip at their rated current, but at a much higher level, which can lead to fires
- Breakers can jam on overcurrent and not trip at all, which can lead to fires
- Breakers can jam when manually moved to "off" which is a safety problem and also possible fire hazard

Some (probably not all) of the bus-connection problems may be mitigated by the bolt-down breakers, but that does not make them acceptably safe. Either way, these panels are a fire hazard and need to be replaced promptly.